# OnClick style change

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to retain the hover style state on my links when I click on them, kind of like a tabbing effect. It doesn't seem to be working, hoping someone can help me with it.

CSS:

```
.nav {
position: absolute;
z-index: 1000;
font-family: Asap;
right: 100px;
top: 70px;

}

.nav a, .nav a:active, .nav a:visited {
font-family: 'Asap', sans-serif;
color: #fff;
font-size: 12px;
text-decoration: none;
text-transform: uppercase;
letter-spacing: 1px;
text-shadow: black 0.1em 0.1em 0.2em;
}

.nav a:hover {
font-family: Asap;
color: #fff;
font-size: 12px;
text-decoration: none;
text-transform: uppercase;
letter-spacing: 1px;
border-top: 2px solid #fff;
padding-top: 5px;
}

.nav2 a {
font-family: Asap;
color: #fff;
font-size: 12px;
text-decoration: none;
text-transform: uppercase;
letter-spacing: 1px;
border-top: 2px solid #fff;
padding-top: 5px;
}
```

Script:

```
$('div.nav > a').click(function(){
$(this).parent().removeClass('nav').addClass('nav2');
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="nav" onclick="javascript:showlayer('myName')">
<span class="btn1"><a href="#page-1" title="Design">Design</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
<span class="btn2"><a href="#page-2" title="Neighbourhood">Neighbourhood</a> 
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
<span class="btn3"><a href="#page-3" title="Media">Media</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
<span class="btn4"><a href="#page-4" title="Media">Developer</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
<span class="btn5"><a href="#page-5" title="Media">Contact</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
</div>
```

Comment: Call me crazy but your '.nav a:hover' css and '.nav2 a' css look identical

Comment: Yup, I'm actually trying to make my links to have the same effect onclick as it does when hovered on.

Comment: I thought so - I would just combine them into the same rules though so at least if you change it it will apply to both (just comma-separate the two selectors before the {). What browser is it doing a different style in? Chrome seems to stay with the same style for :hover and click

Answer (score 1):

You could just do something purely Javascript by declaring a different style onClick.

```
var change = document.getElementById("Link Id");  //Define the link in a variable
change.onClick=function() {           //Activate the function when clicked
  change.style.fontFamily=("Asap");
  change.style.color=("#fff");
  change.style.fontSize=("12px");
  change.style.textDecoration=("none");         //Change the link attributes
  change.style.textTransform=("uppercase");
  change.style.letterSpacing=("1px");
  change.style.borderTop=("2px solid #fff");
  change.style.paddingTop= ("5px");
}
```

This should change the link style to the hover style after you click the link. Just make sure you assign your link an id. Make sure you know basic Javascript like the src tag to call it:

```
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "externaljavascript.js"></script>
```

And don't forget to refrain from using the  tags in the external script.